# Reverse dependency in MSProject (Start-Finish) in 3-task-scenario not understood

Tags: ms-project

I'm kind of experienced with msproject. Nevertheless I ran into a pretty simple problem which I can't solve. Please help. Direct solutions or VBA solutions are welcome.

The case: Three tasks need to be aligned. My brother and my sister visited me and will leave individually (driving home are task bro and task sis). I would like to have tea with the two of them (task tea) in the time before the first of the two is leaving.

```
----- tea (predecessor: sf sis)           
             ---------- bro
     -------------- sis
```

Here tasks are ordered and scheduled perfectly well. BUT: in case my sister is leaving later than my brother, task tea is going to be shifted, too. Not good, by brother might miss the family tea. Solution, I thought, would be a second sf dependency on the tea task (btw: I'm not using forward deps, because in the real world scenario bro and sis are having more complicated dependencies and must not be governed by the family having tea). But to my surprise, tea is shifed after adding the bro-dep as shown here (and my sister is missing the tea):

```
        ----- tea (predecessor: sf sis, sf bro)           
             ---------- bro
     -------------- sis
```

There is an easy solution to this: adding a summary task to bro and sis and building the sf dep of tea to that summary task. That's not applicable in my case, since bro and sis are tasks at very remote structures of the project plan. Ok, your are right, I could create milestone ahead of bro and sis, create a summary task around that milestone and use that one for the tea deps. That would be a solution, but a rather complex, ugly solution for a simple problem. Do you know a better one?

I was searching for a solution, but every thread and explanation only takes two tasks into account as in the first example above, not three.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand exactly what you are tring to achieve, but it sounds like you want both bro and sis tasks to start after the tea task (so both have a sf dependancy on the tea task) but you also want the sis and bro tasks to start at the same time? If so make bro a predecessor of sis with a ss dependancy. The result will be that both will occur after the end of the tea task but the start time of bro and sis will be aligned.

Comment: Bro and Sis are project tasks which have complex dependencies in the real life szenario. Therefore I don't want to change them at all and they should stay (in time) where they are. I want to create a "floating" task, which starts as late as possible and ends before either bro or sis - depending on which one starts first.

Comment: You can set one task to finsh no later than a predecessor task by setting a Finish-Finish dependency on it. You can set a FF dependency back to multiple predecessors, but the subordinate task will finsh no later than the latest finishing predecessor. It is not possible to finish no later than the earliest finishing predecessor.

Comment: Hmm I couldn't let it lie and I think I made it work. So you have two tasks (A & B) starting and ending at different points in time and you want to finish a third task (C) at the earliest of the finish times of the two predecessor tasks? In task C set up two predecessors, A & B, with a Finish to Finish dependency and a NEGATIVE lag of the duration of task C...